# Why we can't call 'println()' method with help of PrintStream class where out is object of this class?

Tags: java, println

Why we can't call `println()` method with help of PrintStream class where out is object of this class?

```
import java.io.*;

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hov This was also queried (& ignored) in their [last thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10670422/418556)!

Comment: @Hov No, just a 'law breaker' according to their nic., ..or perhaps a 'rebel without a clue'.

Comment: Since when is StackOverflow about ridiculing beginners?

Comment: I m new, By mistake i tagged into these house

Comment: Thanks for the information. Down-vote removed and criticism retracted. Again, thank you for recognizing our concerns.

Answer (score 7):

> Why we can't call `println()` method with help of `PrintStream` class where `out` is object of this class:
>
> ```
>  PrintStream.out.println("Hello");
> ```

Three reasons:

a) it's not static - you need an instance of the PrintStream class

b) it's got `protected` visibility - so its not accessibe.

c) the `out` variable is actually an `OutputStream` - so it doesn't have a `println` method.

To use a PrintStream, you want to do something like this:

```
final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)));
ps.println("Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.");
ps.close();
```

Consult the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for more information.

Comment: if we make instance of ti\his class then it is possible?

Comment: No, you can't access the `out` variable directly -- the `protected` visibility prevents this -- you want to invoke one of the `public` methods on the `PrintStream` class.  See also Thihara's answer - to print to the console, you can use `System.out.println("foo")`.

Comment: And a third reason: PrintStream.out is of type OutputStream, not PrintStream, so it doesn't have a println() method. The entire construction makes no sense.

Comment: Yes this implementation is CRIMINAL :-D But I guess he already know that, hence the name ;-)

Comment: "protected"?  i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

Yep what Greg says. Also if you want to print to the console you can just use `System.out.println("Manga Bunga");`

And if you want to use PrintStream use the println() method after instantiating a PrintStreat object.